# NoSuchMethodError with Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I encountered a strange error with Play.

All my tests are OK, but when I run, I have the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: controllers.package$.tuple2Writes(Lplay/api/libs/json/Writes;Lplay/api/libs/json/Writes;)Lplay/api/libs/json/Writes;
```

This method is defined in a package object.

`sbt clean` doesn't fix

Comment: Can you add details about your objects? This looks like an issue with writing a case class. Also, are you exercising the same endpoint in tests that you're accessing when you "run"?

Comment: same endpoint works in test, and clean doesn't fix

Comment: same problem  here